# Read line by line from a file *TCL

Tags: tcl

In TCL, I would like to read line by line from a file (a.txt)

Input file:

---

a1 1000.1111 2000.2222

a2 2222.0001 3333.2224
.
.
.

---

Output file1:

ball a1

---

Output file2:

game [Base ball a1] { 1000.1111 (-10.5) 2000.2222 (+20.785) }

game (Base ball a2] { 2222.0001 (-10.5) 3333.2224 (+20.785) )

Answer (score 2):

To read from a file line-by-line, use `gets` in a loop like this:

```
set f [open "input.file"]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    # Do something with $line in here
}
close $f
```

or read the file all at once with `read` and go over the `split` lines:

```
set f popen "input.file"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
    # Do something with $line in here
}
```

I do not understand fully what you actually wish to do with the lines so I'll let you write that part. However, the *best* way to get the words of a line when you can't be sure that they're just simple (your example snippet *is* just simple) is this:

```
set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
```

Once you have the list of words, there's a whole range of list operations you can do. For example, to divide a line into its first word and the other words, use `lassign`:

```
set remaining [lassign $words gameName]
```

The `format` command may be helpful in producing output.

```
puts $outputFile [format "game (Baseball %s) {%s}" $gameName $statistics]
```

But as I said, the production of the `statistics` is what I really don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple working example follows:

```
set rfp [open "a.txt" r]
set txt [read $rfp]
close $rfp

set text_lines [split $txt "\n"]

set wfp [open "output.txt" w]

foreach line $text_lines {
    if { $line != {} } {
        set val1 [lindex "$line" 0]
        set val2 [lindex "$line" 1]
        set val3 [lindex "$line" 2]
        puts $wfp "game (Base ball $val1) { $val2 (-10.5) $val3 (+20.785) }"
    }
}

close $wfp
```

This will produce a file called `output.txt` reading input from `a.txt` first, with the exact (a sort of) obscure content you need, whatever it is for...

Empty lines are skipped, remember that no further line parsing checks are made, so this implies that a correct formatting is always expected.

`Output file 1` is absolutely meaningless.

Edit paths where needed. Bye.

Comment: You will have an empty element at the end of `$text_lines` because `$txt` ends with a newline. You might want to `set txt [read -nonewline $rfp]`.

Comment: @glennjackman What you say is formally correct, `if { $line != {} }` prevents that empty element at end though. Since `set txt [read -nonewline $rfp]` alone wouldn't avoid blank lines being parsed from source file, I think we should have both. Thanks.